# Use TLS credentials with a common name for #C gRPC

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2, grpc

With the Go gRPC library you can create a tls.Config using a specific common-name.  However, using the gRPC C# library for ChannelCredentials I haven't been able to figure out how to pass the common name as part of the certificate.

Any help or pointers for how to use a common-name when creating a ChannelCredentials would be much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't common-name part of the certificate itself? In C core based languages (including C#), you can override the grpc.ssl_target_name_override channel argument (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/1c73e2c53ddecf3bd45f1c28d23a895fc7cd6e12/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h#L260) but that's only for testing. Here's how to set that channel arg in C#: 
 https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/1c73e2c53ddecf3bd45f1c28d23a895fc7cd6e12/src/csharp/Grpc.IntegrationTesting/InteropClient.cs#L103

Answer (score 1):

```
var channelCredentials = new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText("server.pem"));
var option = new List<ChannelOption>
{
    new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.SslTargetNameOverride, "your-common-name")
};
channel = new Channel(address, channelCredentials, option);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answers are not really useful to understand the concept other than just Copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

[SnowCrumble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6399381/snowcrumble) meant if you use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core) Nuget package to create gRpc-channel then you can set 'common-name' this way:

```
using Grpc.Core;   
... 
var channelCredentials = new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText("server.pem"));
var option = new List<ChannelOption>
{
    new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.SslTargetNameOverride, "your-common-name")
};
channel = new Channel(address, channelCredentials, option);
```

This code override grpc.ssl_target_name_override channel argument.
But as [Jan Tattermusch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5454771/jan-tattermusch) said in his comment: **beware of force changing 'common-name'** because it should be a part of the certificate.